# ast.py error when Caching Web tiles from a service

Tags: python-3.x, caching

I am working on creating cached tiles from our server, for people to load into mobile apps and use offline.

I keep running into ast.py errors on line 44, which is the finishtime = time.clock().  But even when i remove the line for creating reports, i continue to get other ast.py errors.

```
SyntaxError  Traceback (most recent call last)
file: C:\Program Files\ArcGis\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\ast.py, in parse:
line 35: return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

SyntaxError: invalide sytax (<string>, line 44)
```

The string of code that i am trying to run is

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os, sys, time, datetime, traceback, string

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "E:\2_Data\MapTileCache"

# List of input variables for map service properties
connectionFile = r"C:\Users\<ommitted>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcCatalog"
server          = "ommitted"
serviceName         = "World_Street_Map_2D.MapServer"
inputService        = connectionFile + "\\" + server + "\\" + serviceName
targetCachePath     = "E:\2_Data\MapTileCache\Tiles"
exportCacheType     = "TILE_PACKAGE"
copyDataFromServer  = "DO_NOT_COPY"
storageFormat       = "COMPACT"
scales          = [500000,250000,125000,64000]
numOfCachingServiceInstances = "2"
areaOfInterest      = "E:\2_Data\MapTileCache\ATAK_ext.shp"
exportExtents       = ""
overwriteTiles      = "MERGE"

currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
arg1 = currentTime.strftime("%H-%M")
arg2 = currentTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

report = open(file, 'w')

try:
    starttime = time.clock()
    result = arcpy.server.ExportMapServerCache(inputService, targetCachePath, exportCacheType, copyDataFromServer, storageFormat, scales, numOfCachingServiceInstances, areaOfInterest, exportExtents, overwriteTiles)

finishtime = time.clock()
elapsedtime = finistime - startime

while result.status < 4:
        time.sleep(0.2)
resultValue = result.getMessages()
report.write ("completed " + str(resultValue))

print ("Exported cache successfully for mapservice " + serviceName + " To " + \targetcachepath + " in " + str(elapsedtime) + " sec \n on " + arg2)

except Exception as e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    report.write("Failed at \n" "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno)
    report.write(str(e))

print("Exported Map server Cache  using area of Interest")

report.close()
```

I am not sure what this ast.py file is doing, is it broke or is it properly identifying an issue in my code and i just dont know how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have a `try:`, you also need to have `except:`. Otherwise, you will get this `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Comment: I had an except line
```
except Exception as e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    report.write("Failed at \n" "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno)
    report.write(str(e))
```
But it's throwing errors

Comment: Please place what you wrote in the comment directly in the body of your question, so the code is clear. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/server/export-map-server-cache.htm

This is the site i am pullling from and just replacing my specifics for the variables. It throws ast.py errors (line 35 within ast.py), and syntaxerror (string) at line 44  or the finishtime = time.clock() line

Comment: In the code you posted, you have incorrect indentation. Everything after `try:` until `except:` needs to be indented, as shown in the link.